# What is wrong with this sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Calpurnia is Atticus’ housekeeper. She plays a large role in Jem and Scout growing up- almost like a mother figure to them, and most definitely the biggest female role that the children are exposed to.

Comment: She may play a large role in Jem and Scout's *life* but not in them directly.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with it, per se - there might be style choices that others would make, though. Is there something specific you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Calpurnia is Atticus’ housekeeper. She plays a large role in Jem and **{Scout's} {growing-up} -- {she is}** almost like a mother figure to them, and **is** most definitely the <s>biggest</s> **most significant** female role that the children are exposed to.

(I've used curly braces to help you distinguish between the individual corrections I have made.)